# Search whole javascript object with children

Tags: javascript, object, search

I currently have this object:

```
var obj = {
    1: {
    title: 'test',
    children: {
        2: {
        title: 'test2',
        children: {}
      },
      3: {
        title: 'test3',
        children: {}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The whole idea is I make a function to add an item to this object. As parameter I send the parent.

Now, I was wondering how I would get the right item object. For example if I send parent '2', it would get 2: from the children of 1:. The only way I can think of is a for loop, but I don't know if there's a more efficient way. The children can be extended even more, so a parent has children, those children have children endlessly. That's the whole idea at least.

I think with a few items a for loop is okay, but I think if I have over 50 items it's already slow, and it'll even be slower with more.

Comment: *"if I have over 50 items it's already slow"* – well, depends on your definition of "slow", but a 50-time recursion would take at most fractions of milliseconds. In any case...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find property by name in a deep object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642494/find-property-by-name-in-a-deep-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution use `Object.keys()` for getting all keys of the given object and an array iteration with short ciruit `Array.prototype.some()` looks for the key. If found the reference is returned, otherwise the item is checked for an object. If so the object reference is taken for a new search with `getReference()`.

```js
var obj = { 1: { title: 'test', children: { 2: { title: 'test2', children: {} }, 3: { title: 'test3', children: {} } } } };

function getReference(o, p) {
    var r;
    Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
        if (k === p) {
            r = o[k];
            return true;
        }
        if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            r = getReference(o[k], p);
            return !!r;
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var x = getReference(obj, '2');
document.write(x.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want adding to be fast, you can preserve indexes of your child nodes in object or map (ES6). It could look like this:

```
function Tree() {
    this.data = {};
    this.indexes = {0: this.data};
}

Tree.prototype = {
    addNode: function(parentIndex, index, node) {
        // handle cases when parentIndex does not exist
        // handle cases when index already exists
        this.indexes[index] = node;
        var parent = this.indexes[parentIndex];
        parent.children = parent.children || {};
        parent.children[index] = node;            
    }
}

var tree = new Tree();

tree.addNode(0, 1, { title: 'test' });
tree.addNode(1, 2, { title: 'test2' });
tree.addNode(1, 3, { title: 'test3' });

console.log(tree.data);
```