# Extract deeply nested child objects by property name with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have arrays of deeply nested objects.  I would like to write a function to extract arbitrary child objects from these arrays.  In some cases values of nested properties are values and objects, in other cases they are arrays.

Examples of arrays are below:

```
[{parent: {level1: {level2: 'data'}}}]

[{parent: {level1: [{level2: {...}}, {level2: {...}}, {level2: {...}}]}}]

[{parent: {level1: [{level2: {level3: 'data'}}, {level2: {..}}, {level2: {..}}]}}]
```

Calling extraction function on such an array should result in an array of objects that we're interested in.

Examples of calling the function and its results for the example arrays above:

```
extractChildren(source, 'level2') = [{level2: 'data'}]

extractChildren(source, 'level2') = [{level2: {...}, level2: {...}, level2: {...}]

extractChildren(source, 'level3') = [{level3: 'data'}]
```

Is there a concise way to achieve this with `lodash` or I should use regular JavaScript to iterate through properties?

P.S. Think of it as equivalent of XPath `select all nodes with the name "nodename"`

Comment: You should also explain with an example what child objects should be extracted, exactly, especially with regard to how the result should look like if one potential target contains another potential target.

Comment: Show more, please.  Can you provide an expected input, the "call", and expected output?

Comment: Your example is invalid, you can't keep multiple items with the same key in same level.

Comment: @Festo those are there different example arrays

Comment: @kyrylkov with your latest update, yes ;)

Comment: @Festo Slow thinking after a long work day :(

Answer (score 1):

I hope, it helps:

```
'use strict';

let _ = require("lodash");
let source = [{parent: {level1: [{level2: {level3: 'data'}}, {level2: {}}, {level2: {}}]}}];

function extractChildren(source, specKey) {
    let results = [];
    let search = function(source, specKey) {
        _.forEach(source, function(item) {
            if (!!item[specKey]) {
                let obj = {};
                obj[specKey] = item[specKey];
                results.push(obj);
                return;
            }

            search(item, specKey);
        });
    };

    search(source, specKey);
    return results;
};

console.log(extractChildren(source, 'level3'));
// [ { level3: 'data' } ]
```

Comment: Ends up with `Maximum call stack size exceeded` with default Node.js config and my actual data

Comment: How big is your data?

Comment: Up to 10 levels deep or so, but not very big (tens of KB), since otherwise I would use streams.  Nevermind.  I still need to approach the problem differently since I need to gather some data from parent objects also and such simple `extractChildren` function won't work for that case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642494/find-property-by-name-in-a-deep-object):

Elegant:

```
function find_obj_by_name(obj, key) {
    if( !(obj instanceof Array) ) return [];

    if (key in obj)
        return [obj[key]];

    return _.flatten(_.map(obj, function(v) {
        return typeof v == "object" ? find_obj_by_name(v, key) : [];
    }), true);
}
```

Efficient:

```
function find_obj_by_name(obj, key) {
    if( !(obj instanceof Array) ) return [];

    if (key in obj)
        return [obj[key]];

    var res = [];
    _.forEach(obj, function(v) {
        if (typeof v == "object" && (v = find_obj_by_name(v, key)).length)
            res.push.apply(res, v);
    });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The "efficient" can be improved by using vanilla `forEach` instead of `_.forEach`

Comment: Also, I don't understand what is this `fn(v, key)`. did you test this? what is `fn`?

Comment: I now see you have copied another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15643385/104380), changed it, and didn't verify the result.

Comment: ...yes, I referenced the other answer in my post. Maybe you didn't see the link in the first line? I also tested this answer, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You serous? `fn` is undefined, so how can you possibly claim you've tested it

Comment: Great catch! `fn` should have been `find_obj_by_name`. Many thanks for your diligent efforts. Note that a test on a non-nested object will succeed because it never hits the `forEach` condition. Maybe you can suggest some more thorough unit tests for this?

Comment: Maybe add `if( !(obj instanceof Array) ) return []` at the beginning, no?

Comment: I would even change the name from `obj` to `arr` so it would be clear that an array should be passed to the function. and also perhaps also change `v` to `obj`