# What's the difference between a regular push and an Array.prototype.push.apply

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, apply

I don't quite understand the difference between the following two lines of code. In my code, the line with "apply" works the way I want it to, and the line with just regular push doesn't.

So what is really going on when both of these are executed:

```
//this one does not work the way i want it to
$scope.items.push(result.data.stuff)

//this one works!
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items, result.data.stuff);
```

Edit: sorry for confusion, I fixed it so that it has the "push" method in there

Comment: There is no line with a "regular push"? And yes, I'm pretty sure that `$cope.items.push(result.data.stuff[0], results.data.stuff[1], …)` would have worked.

Comment: [MDN apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Sorry for confusion...I fixed it. Please see the push line again.

Answer (score 18):

Basic difference is explained on [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

You can read there:

> You can use push to append an element to an array. And, because push
>   accepts a variable number of arguments, you can also push multiple
>   elements at once.
>
> **But, if you pass an array to push, it will actually add that array as**
>   **a single element, instead of adding the elements individually. So you**
>   **end up with an array inside an array.**

So if you do something like this:

```
let numbersArray = [1, 2]
numbersArray.push([3, 4])
```

You will have an array in array:

```
[1, 2, [3,4]]
```

When you have a list of variables which you want to add, you can use push.apply()

```
let numbersArray = [1, 2]
numbersArray.push.apply(numbersArray, [3, 4])
```

Then your result will looks like that:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 15):

New 1. That pushes the array onto items.

```
$scope.items = [1, 2];
result.data.stuff = [3, 4];
$scope.items.push(result.data.stuff);
$scope.items[0] === 1;
$scope.items[1] === 2;
$scope.items[2][0] === 3;
$scope.items[2][1] === 4;
```

Old 1. Drops the existing reference that was in `$scope.items`.

```
$scope.items = [1, 2];
result.data.stuff = [3, 4];
$scope.items = result.data.stuff;
$scope.items[0] === 3;
$scope.items[1] === 4;
```

2. Pushes all the items from `result.data.stuff` into `$scope.items`, keeping the existing items.

```
$scope.items = [1, 2];
result.data.stuff = [3, 4];
Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items, result.data.stuff);
$scope.items[0] === 1;
$scope.items[1] === 2;
$scope.items[2] === 3;
$scope.items[3] === 4;
```

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting, there seems to be a markdown bug.

Comment: Or you just did not indent with 8 spaces. ;) fixed

Comment: @DeepakA what do you mean?

Answer (score 12):

`Array.prototype.push()` is a method that adds one or more elements to the end of the array and returns the new length of the array.  `Array.prototype.push.apply()` takes the original array and an array which contains elements to add to the original array.

Example for `Array.prototype.push()`:

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 2, 8];
numbers.push(3, 4, 6, 7);
console.log(numbers); // [1, 5, 2, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Example for `Array.prototype.push()` with nested arrays:

```
var foods = [['apples', 'pears']];
foods.push(['lettuce', 'celery']);
console.log(foods); // [['apples', 'pears'], ['lettuce', 'celery']]
```

Example for `Array.prototype.push.apply()`:

```
var grades = [90, 88, 83, 85];
var more_grades = [79, 84, 81, 90];
Array.prototype.push.apply(grades, more_grades);
console.log(grades); // [90, 88, 83, 85, 79, 84, 81, 90]
```

Example for `Array.prototype.push.apply()` with nested arrays:

```
var sports = [['running', 'cycling']];
var other_sports = [['football', 'basketball']];
Array.prototype.push.apply(sports, other_sports);
console.log(sports);
// [['running', 'cycling'], ['football', 'basketball']]
```

References:

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 7):

`push()` will add on one index for every argument you pass in. It does not care what it is adding to the array. What every you tell to add it will add it to the end of the array.

When you use [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it will take the array that you have supplied as the second argument and convert it to multiple arguments. [MDN explains it well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions), but it basically turns it into

```
yourArray.push(argument[0],argument[1],argument[2],argument[3]);
```

Comment: This is the very answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

see:[MDN:Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions);

Please note the note on this page:

> Note: While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of call(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value, and **arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object)**. All the items within the argsArray(second parameter) will be used for `Array.prototype.push` in order.It is the same to :

`$scope.items.push.apply($scope.items, result.data.stuff)`;

Because `$scope.items.push === Array.prototype.push` and `apply()` accepts an array-like parameter but [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) accepts an arguments list;

Briefly speaking, `apply` will translate array-like parameter into pieces for that function.

Comment: Please keep SO posts to English

Comment: Aha! I'm new here and my english may be a little poor@Bergi

Comment: Well, our Chinese (?) is even poorer… See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/183280

Comment: The Chinese above is a simple description of the English before it.

Answer (score 0):

I think 
`$scope.items = result.data.stuff`
not equvivalent to 
`Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.items, result.data.stuff);`

because the first reallocates the array (clears the old elements)

try this:

```
$scope.items.push(result.data.stuff[0], result.data.stuff[1], ...);
```

or

`$scope.items.push.apply($scope.items, result.data.stuff);`

The above on equals to call Array.prototype.push.apply because $scope.items is an array (we think it)

there's an other joiner function:

```
$scope.items = $scope.items.concat(result.data.stuff);
```

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I meant. item.push(result.data.stuff). But it doesn't work the way I want to

Comment: I have corrected it: items.push(result.data.stuff) is putting the whole result.data.stuff array as one item into items, but Array.prototype.push.apply 's second parameter is an array of arguments so that insert each element into $scope.items. 
$scope.items = $scope.items.concat(result.data.stuff); also merges the two array