# Run Google spreadsheet macro without time restriction

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to run a google spreadsheet macro (macro.gs) that has to download a huge number of google site links belonging to a domain, but it takes a long time to execute, so the script ends and it is not yet done. I have read that this is designed to be like that (time limited execution), so there's not much I can do there.

```
function listSites() {
  var domain="domain";
  var PAGE_LENGTH=200;
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain,0,PAGE_LENGTH);
  for(var i=0; sites.length != 0; i+=PAGE_LENGTH){
    for (var j=0; j<sites.length; j++) {
      sheet.appendRow([sites[j].getUrl()]);
    }
    sites = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, i, PAGE_LENGTH);
  }
};
```

However, I have also read that I can try to run a "Task Queue" with Google Apps Script to run it without time limits, but I am not sure if I can run a spreadsheet macro inside a task to evade that time limit.

So far all that I've read does not give any information about how to do it.

Comment: There are a lot of macro tasks that should take only a second or two, but if poorly implemented (read: used as-recorded) can take *much* longer. Some examples would be copying values to different places and changing formatting. I recommend you either share a code example or describe a bit what your macro is doing. Also: you should provide references to research you perform. Apps Script code always has a time limit, but the duration varys based on the usage environment (from 30s to 30m, usually 6m).

Comment: I've added the script that gets executed. I think the problem is not implementation, but the fact that there are a lot of sites.

Comment: Create a output array and use `setValues()` instead of  appendRow. Share your execution transcript too to further optimise.

Answer (score 0):

Appending a row is really only appropriate if your sheet is volatile, e.g. you can not be certain that new data was added in between the time you calculate the last row and the time you add your new data.

The alternative is to build your output and then serialize it in a single write, using`setValues` with a rectangular 2d `Array`:

```
function writeAllSiteUrls() {
  const domain = "domain",
      PAGE_LENGTH = 200,
      output = [];

  var i = 0;
  do {
    var search = SitesApp.getAllSites(domain, i * PAGE_LENGTH, PAGE_LENGTH);
    var urls = search.map(function (site) {
      return site.getUrl();
    });
    Array.prototype.push.apply(output, urls);
    ++i;
  } while (search.length);

  if (!output.length)
    return;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() +1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

You could certainly build a more complex return object rather than just the site URL, but that wasn't really your question. Also note that any Apps Script code dealing with Google Sites deals with only the "old" version of Google Sites - those made with the new version are not accessible:

> A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. Apps Script cannot currently access or modify Sites made with this version, but script can still access classic Sites.

References

- [`Array.prototype.push.apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638761/9337071)
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Range#setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Google Sites: Old vs. New](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/7176163?hl=en)