# Find element in map

Tags: javascript

I have a map of objects:

```
"0": {
    key: 'id',
    value: {
        name: "eval"
        // other variables
    }
},
"1": {
    key: 'id',
    value: {
        name: "help"
        // other variables
    }
} // and so on
```

I need to find an element in map that's `name` variable is eqaul to "eval". What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: inb4: I am talking about maps, not objects

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: you sent a link to the <Array>.map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<Array>.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert [map values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) to array and after [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) what you want.

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set(0, {
  key: 'id',
    value: {
      name: "eval"
    }
});

map.set(1, {
  key: 'id',
    value: {
      name: "help"
    }
});

const result = Array.from(map.values())
  .filter(x => x.value.name === 'eval')[0];
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If "map" is an array

```
let arr = [{key:'id', value:{ name:'eval' }}]
let item = arr.find(el => el.value.name == 'eval')
```

If "map" is an object

```
let obj = {0:{key:'id', value:{ name:'eval' }}}
let item = Object.values(obj).find(el => el.value.name == 'eval')
```

Answer (score 0):

The good old forEach Loop can do it too.

```js
const data = [{
    key: 'id',
    value: {
        name: "eval"
        // other variables
    }
},
{
    key: 'id',
    value: {
        name: "help"
        // other variables
    }
}]

let res = [];
data.forEach((el) => {
  if (el.value.name === "eval") {
    res.push(el);
  }  
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
const tmp = {
  "0": {
    key: "id",
    value: {
      name: "eval"
      // other variables
    }
  },
  "1": {
    key: "id",
    value: {
      name: "eval"
      // other variables
    }
  }
};

function findEval(obj, target) {
    const elem = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => tmp[key].value.name === target);
    return elem.map(e => obj[e]);
}
console.log(findEval(tmp, 'eval'))
```

but better use lodash [Find property by name in a deep object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642494/find-property-by-name-in-a-deep-object)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

simple and best solution

```
const tmp = {
  "0": {
    key: "id",
    value: {
      name: "eval"
      // other variables
    }
  },
  "1": {
    key: "id",
    value: {
      name: "eval"
      // other variables
    }
  }
};

function findEval(obj, target) {
    for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].value.name === target) {
            return obj[i].value.name;
        }
    }
}
console.log(findEval(tmp, 'eval'))
```