# Why the javascript function shown below in the code section is not working in Firefox and Chrome? but works fine in IE

Tags: javascript

This code is responsible for preventing users from entering non-numeric characters such any any ascii except number [0-9]. Works fine in in IE, but not in Firefox and Chrome. Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you

```
'oKeyPress': function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    return !(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57));
}
```

Comment: Note the use of `navigator.appName` to decide which property to use for the key code, [that's not a good way of doing it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573881/why-the-javascript-navigator-appname-returns-netscape-for-safari-firefox-and-ch).

Comment: For how to fix it, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which - the second answer shows how.

Comment: Though the event name may also be wrong, just noticed the 'oKeyPress' presumably that should be 'onKeyPress'?

Comment: Netscape check, yikes, burn whatever you used to get that reference. `var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;`

Comment: @epascarello: There's also `e.charCode`.  jQuery has `e.charCode != null ? e.charCode : e.keyCode` where `e.which` isn't already set.

Answer (score 2):

Use [feature detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html#link2); not browser detection:

```
var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

inside your `KeyPress` event to get the `charcode` use this:

```
return (window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your suggestions and feedback; I just found out why it did not work on Firefox and chrome before. The reason it was not working was because I was using something like this code from my Code-behind C# code :

```
this.txtApsId.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return (function(e) {var charCode = (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') ? e.which : e.keyCode; return charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57); }(event || window.event))");
```

Thanks