# How to Hide and Show SELECT Options with JQuery in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-select

I'm trying to hide some options from a drop down. JQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` work great in Firefox and Chrome, but no luck in IE.

Any good ideas?

Comment: Can we see some code maby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hide and Show the Options based on Browser detection**

Of many possible approaches, this method requires browser sniffing, which can be unstable, but on the other hand with this approach we don't have to swap in and out multiple copies of the same `select` list.

```
//To hide elements
$("select option").each(function(index, val){
    if ($(this).is('option') && (!$(this).parent().is('span')))
        $(this).wrap((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? '<span>' : null).hide();
});

//To show elements
$("select option").each(function(index, val) {
    if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        if (this.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'OPTION') {
            var span = $(this).parent();
            var opt = this;
            if($(this).parent().is('span')) {
                $(opt).show();
                $(span).replaceWith(opt);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(this).show(); //all other browsers use standard .show()
    }
});
```

Credit for this lies squarely with Dima Svirid here: http://ajax911.com/hide-options-selecbox-jquery/

Comment: This works, yet ultimately a better and cleaner cross-browser solution is to create, add, and remove select items in real time with script.

Comment: Excellent @tony :) Works perfectly!

Comment: This is incredibly hacky, though sadly the only solution I could find for a project that would have required a significant recode to implement any other method. Cheers.

Comment: Yes it is hacky indeed.

Comment: Saved a lot of time for me from recoding  when i encountered this stupid IE bug.

Comment: Hi, i tryed this with Internet Explorer 11... but navigator.appName is "Netscape" for I.E. 11...

Comment: For testing IE 11, read at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447373/how-can-i-target-only-internet-explorer-11-with-javascript/17447718#17447718

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention that IE11 navigator.appName returns 'Netscape' :)
So taking it into consideration:

```
$("select option[value='your_option_value']").wrap((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' || navigator.appName == 'Netscape') ? '<span>' : null).hide();
```

Comment: This is a good point. However, other browsers can [choose to return 'Netscape' here too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573881/why-does-javascript-navigator-appname-return-netscape-for-safari-firefox-and-ch), so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather simple solution, although the options will not be hidden but disabled on IE.

```
$('#delivery_time option[value="06:30"]').removeAttr('disabled').show();       // To Show/Enable
$('#delivery_time option[value="06:30"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide(); // To Hide/Disable
```

Here is the source where I stumbled upon these 2 lines: [IT Support Guides - Internet Explorer – How to hide select options using jQuery](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/internet-explorer-how-to-hide-select-options-using-jquery/)