# Dropdown filter doesn't work in IE

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I hired someone to build a page for me in Wordpress. It works fine in Google Chrome, but using Internet Explorer I seem to have problems with the filter he used on the dropdown list.

This is the code I have. So the first dropdown allows the user to select a country and the second dropdown allows the user to select an airport, with a filter on the selected country. Using Internet Explorer this doesn't work at all.

I can't find anything wrong in the code, but I'm definitely no professional.

```
global $wpdb;
$country_query = "SELECT a.AirportName, a.AirportCode, c.CountryName, c.CountryCode FROM booking_airport as a LEFT JOIN booking_country as c ON c.CountryCode = a.AirportCountryCode";
$country_info = $wpdb->get_results($country_query);
$countries = array();
foreach($country_info as $country_details) {
    if(!array_key_exists($country_details->CountryCode,$countries)) {
        $countries[$country_details->CountryCode] = $country_details->CountryName;
    }
    $depart_airports[] = "<option value=\"$country_details->AirportCode\" class=\"d_airport $country_details->CountryCode\">$country_details->AirportName</option>";
    $return_airports[] = "<option value=\"$country_details->AirportCode\" class=\"r_airport $country_details->CountryCode\">$country_details->AirportName</option>";
}

<select name="departure_country" id="departure_country" style="padding-left: 1%;">
<option value="0"><?php echo $select_country; ?></option>
<?php
foreach($countries as $k=>$v) {
    echo "<option value=\"$k\">$v</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="departure_airport" id="departure_airport" style="padding-left: 1%;">
<option value="0"><?php echo $select_airport; ?></option>
<?php
foreach($depart_airports as $airport) {
    echo $airport;
}
?>
</select>
```

You can visit the website [here](http://twd-support.com/book-transport/).

Comment: go back to the guy you hired

Comment: There's likely a lot of related code that you're leaving out. Can you provide any more?

Comment: @Dagon, that's the problem. Once he received payments I never heard from him again ...

Comment: @PatrickQ, yeah sure! I'll see if I can find any related info

Comment: @PatrickQ, I think this is all the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the Javascript that adjusts the contents of the departure airport select list is using jQuery(option class).hide() to hide them. This adds `style="display: none;"` to the option.

IE does not support `display:none` on options.

I suggest that you search StackOverflow. One example of how do handle this is [How to Hide and Show SELECT Options with JQuery in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736396/how-to-hide-and-show-select-options-with-jquery-in-ie).

Comment: Bob, thank you very much! I'll check out that example tomorrow. Hopefully it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not the html thats causing the problem. The issue lies in the css, i just inspected your code and it looks like there are many rules that are just applied for chrome browsers. in your css anything that starts with -webkit- means its just for chrome and safari. You will have to add 2 other rules besides this, 1 for -moz- mozilla and a standard one as well. Which version of IE are you using? it should work fine on IE10+. I also see that you are using bootstrap framework, so you can also replace these functionality with the default one from bootstrap and then modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Wow really, just CSS? Damn ... I'm using IE 11. I'll try and fix that.

Comment: @bobdye is right, it is a css error but using jquery to solve it might be better. One way would be to disable the options instead of hiding.
.css("disabled","disabled");

Another way would be to use .hideOption();  and .showOption();