# How to Hide and Show OPTIONS of a dropdown with JQuery in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736396/how-to-hide-and-show-select-options-with-jquery-in-ie) to get it working. It works fine on Firefox and Chrome but doesn't work on IE as always. My idea about the Javascript function was i look in the first option box and look when it get changed. When changed it should grab the value of the the option box and look for it in the second one. Then display just the Optionswith the same value.

The PHP code :

```
<label style="width:100px;float:left;">f&uuml;r das Revier:*</label>
    <select class="required"  id="reviernummer" style="width:240px;"name="verhaltenscode" ' >
    <?php $selected = $arrayAktuellerDatensatz['verhaltenscode'];?>
        <option selected ="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $selected; ?></option>
        <?php loadselect('kataster', 'Fischereibuchzahl', 'Fischereibuchzahl');?>
    </select><br />

    <select class="required" id="verhaltenscode" style="width:240px;" name="verhaltenscode">
        <?php $selected = $arrayAktuellerDatensatz['verhaltenscode_neu'];?>
        <option selected ="selected" value="<?php echo $selected; ?>"><?php echo $selected; ?></option>
        <?php loadselect('helpbrutstatus', 'Brutstatus', 'Brutstatus');?>
```

loadselect function:

```
if ($tblname == 'kataster'){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM kataster";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fieldvalue = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $fieldcaption = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $lat = $row['Benennung']?>
        <option title="<?php echo $lat; ?>" value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>"><?php echo $fieldcaption .'&nbsp;|&nbsp;'.$lat?></option> <?php
        }
    }
    else if ($tblname == 'helpbrutstatus'){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM helpbrutstatus" ;

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $fieldvalue = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $status = $row['Fischereibuchzahl'];
        $fieldcaption = $row['Brutstatus']; ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $fieldvalue;?>" title="<?php echo $status;?>"  class="sorted">
        <?php echo $status."&nbsp;|&nbsp;".$fieldcaption?></option>  <?php
        }
}
```

Javascript function:

```
reviernummer.onchange = function() {
  var look = $("#reviernummer").val();
  $("option[class='sorted']").each(function(index, val) {
    if ($(this).is('option') && (!$(this).parent().is('span')))
      $(this).wrap((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? '<span>' : null).hide();
  });
  $("option[title='" + look + "']").each(function(index, val) {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
      if (this.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'OPTION') {
        var span = $(this).parent();
        var opt = this;
        if ($(this).parent().is('span')) {
          $(opt).show();
          $(span).replaceWith(opt);
        }
      }
    } else {
      $(this).show(); //all other browsers use standard .show()
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Line 3 of the php code: `<?php <?php `????

Comment: It's not my code. I am sorry. i just got it like that and actually i don't have the time to debug all this php code. I just want the Javascript to get to work.

Comment: How can you get the JS to work if the PHP is invalid?

Comment: the PHP works and the JS works i don't know why but i know that the mistake must be in the Javascript. I tried it once before with this

 reviernummer.onchange = function(){
    var look=$("#reviernummer").val();
    alert(look);
    $("option[class='sorted']").hide();
 $("option[title='"+look+"']").show();

and it worked also on IE

Comment: The PHP was a formatting error by copy and paste sorry.

Comment: Please can you edit the code to show the proper version then please? It'll throw off a lot of people otherwise

Comment: already done. I am very sorry. dont want to scare of people.