# Browser name, version value returns "Netscape"

Tags: javascript

Using some simple JavaScript, I'm getting what seems to be an incorrect value returned for one of my two pieces of similar code.  For `browserName` I am getting Netscape as the value returned regardless of what browser I test the code on.  `browserVer`, however, seems to return the correct value, shown below using Google Chrome.

`browserVer` results:

5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1

Why is this?

```
    var browserName = navigator.appName;
    var browserVer = navigator.appVersion;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google of what `navigator.appName` actually means returns [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.appName) which includes the fact that:

> The HTML5 specification also allows any browser to return "Netscape" here, for compatibility reasons.

Instead, you should probably use a browser sniffing library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: Yep, after changing the wording of my search I found the same thing.  Thanks for the share re: Modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

A better search revealed the answer ([Why does JavaScript navigator.appName return Netscape for Safari, Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573881/why-the-javascript-navigator-appname-returns-netscape-for-safari-firefox-and-ch))

*"MDN says: "This was originally part of DOM Level 0, but has been since included in the HTML5 spec."
See Mozilla documentation here.
BTW; that's why this cannot be used for browser detection (maybe only for IE). Browser detection is a BAD practice and you should always avoid it where possible. Do feature detection instead. But if anybody insists on this; they should use the userAgent property instead."*