# Detect the user browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I am using the following code to discover the user browser:

```
navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
```

It always worked, but IE11 is returning `Netscape`

I have read that Browser detection is a bad practice. ([Why does JavaScript navigator.appName return Netscape for Safari, Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573881/why-the-javascript-navigator-appname-returns-netscape-for-safari-firefox-and-ch)), and we should detect feature. But the [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx) of MS is teaching me how to detect the IE browser.

In the IE11, even the userAgent metions IE:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C;
>   InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko

This being said:

**What is the right way to know what I have to use?**

For example, if I am using IE, the command is:

```
window.document.execCommand('Stop');
```

else, the command is

```
window.stop()
```

**Taking a ride, what is the correct way to know if the browser supports HTML5?**

Comment: regarding to your last question please refer [here](http://html5test.com/).

Comment: How do they know my browser?

Comment: You really ought to read about using feature detection rather than browser detection.  Browser detection is brittle and can break each time a new browser is released.  Feature detection don't right is both forward and backward compatible.

Comment: Is http://modernizr.com/ really not that popular?

Comment: window.stop ? window.stop() : document.execCommand('Stop');

Comment: @dandavis - as mentioned below, when you're not paying attention and creating an element with the ID `stop` or `function stop() ..` in the global scope, you're screwed, and many people will have no idea why it no longer works.

Comment: This question had very interesting solutions and a good discussion about the correct way to do it. I am happy with the comments and answers. Thank you all.

Comment: @adeneo: i think the error message for the div case is instructive as to the issue. the custom global function is another problem, but not impossible to debug. in general, i think some caution is warranted, but we don't want to validate ourselves back to the stone age of strong type computing. my concern with the proposed answer (and why i commented) is that it's hard to tell what commands execCommand supports (i've not seen 'Stop'), so feature detecting it is not reliable, whereas the window.stop issues can happen to any native... how do you debug a failed execCommand?

Comment: It is never easy to develop for web. We need to know a lot of languages: client-side, server-side, database language, CSS, etc... We need to worry about cross-browsing. We need to know about DNS, where to host our page, etc... Now the people wants iOS and Android apps (not only jquery mobile). I think it could be something simpler, like the old desktop apps (vb.net, for example) [I guess I am getting old, and I am only 38 yo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way would be to just check for the feature, as you've mentioned, and never do browser sniffing at all.

```
function stop() {
    if ('execCommand' in document) {
       document.execCommand('Stop');
    }else{
       window.stop()
    }
}
```

To do it the other way around, you could just polyfill window.stop with execCommand, like this

```
if (! ( typeof window.stop == 'function' && 
        window.stop.toString().indexOf('native code') != -1
      )
) {
    window.stop = function () {
        document.execCommand('Stop');
    }
}
```

That would also make sure it's the native method, and is tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Comment: Don't you want your detection the other way around as in `if ('stop' in window)` so you favor using `window.stop()` if it exists?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was worried that someone would do `<div id="stop"></div>`, and suddenly `window.stop` is not what you think it is

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood that I need to look for the feature but I was not knowing how to do it.

Comment: Then, check if `window.stop` is a function.

Comment: How to do it @jfriend00? How to detect if somthing is a function?

Comment: And then someone creates a stop function in the global scope, and it's the same, it's just such a common name, however Chrome at least doesn't seem to overwrite the native `stop` function at all unless you create a new function with the same name.

Comment: @Nizam - you can check if something is a function with `if (typeof window.stop === "function")`.

Comment: I get your point about the global conflict with `stop`.  What I was concerned about is that `execCommand` is supported, but not the `"stop"` verb.  When I read the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand), I see lots of `execCommand` verbs, but no `"stop"` which could give your logic problems.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I'm  not sure if any other browser than IE really support `execCommand('stop')`, but they all support `window.stop`, except IE, so it's a good point, one just has to make sure not to use the word `stop` in the  global scope, as in IE the previously mentioned `<div id="stop"></div>` would most likely create `window.stop` as there's no global native method to protect, and suddenly a check for `window.stop` fails etc. Checking if it's a function would at least fix that problem, then you'd just have to make sure not to create a `stop` function anywhere else.

Comment: If you have `<div id="stop"></div>`, Chrome and Firefox do not override the `window.stop()` function.  As best I know, they only make those auto globals if nothing else occupies that property.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes, I've already tested it and mentioned it above, but in IE where there is no native `window.stop` it probably would, making a simple test for that property somewhat prone to an error that can be hard to track down, so checking it it's of type function is still a good idea.

Comment: In your `if` statement, why use `window.stop && typeof window.stop == 'function'` instead of just `typeof window.stop === 'function'`?  Doesn't the latter cover both cases with less code?

Comment: @jfriend00 - That's true, just old habit of checking if the property exists before trying to use it, but the typeof check would cover that as well, as it would be `undefinded` if doesn't exists. Changed it

Comment: Sorry to be picking here, but doesn't your `.indexOf()` check need to check for `-1` rather than just truthy/falsey?

Comment: @jfriend00 - it will never be zero, if it's the native method it returns `function() {[ native method ]}` or something similar in all browsers, never just `native method`.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of my point.  The case when "native method" is not present is `-1` which is the same truthy value as the case when it is present (some non-zero value).  So, it is always truthy.  Doesn't seem like it's working if it's always truthy.  It seems you want to know when it's `!== -1` so you know it's native code.

Answer (score 0):

Well wouldn't it be cool if there was a *JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features in the user’s browser* so that you could know if a certain feature is supported instead of relying on browser detection (version nightmares ahead)...

There is... [**modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/)

***From the [Docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/)*:**

---

**Why use Modernizr?**
Taking advantage of cool new web technologies is great fun, until you have to support browsers that lag behind. Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

**How it works**
Modernizr runs quickly on page load to detect features; it then creates a JavaScript object with the results, and adds classes to the html element for you to key your CSS on. Modernizr supports dozens of tests, and optionally includes YepNope.js for conditional loading of external .js and .css resources.

**An Example *(also from the docs)***

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

In this example, we decided that we should load a different script depending on whether geolocation is supported in the host browser or not. By doing this, you save users from having to download code that their browser does not need. This increases page performance, and offers a clear place to build a healthy amount of abstraction to your polyfills (both 'geo.js' and 'geo-polyfill.js' would seem the same to the rest of the app, even if they're implemented differently).

IMO `modernizr` is the de facto feature detection JavaScript Library and I use it on ALL my projects. It does have a slight learning curve, but the docs are great, and cover pretty much every feature, and the flexibility it provides you within the above example alone is enough of a reason to use it.