# Netscape in JavaScript returns an error in the browser's console

Tags: javascript, netscape

I'm wondering why isn't `netscape` working using **JS**

```
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape" && parseInt(navigator.appVersion.charAt(0)) >= 4){
  //netscape should work, but the code doesn't work and I get an error in the console
  netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
  //uncaught ReferenceError: netscape is not defined
  window.open(
    "URL",
    "Name",
    "menubar=off, toolbar=off, location=off, personalbar=off, status=off, minimizable=off, resizable=off, directories=off, chrome=on, dialog=off, titlebar=no, alwaysRaised=on, close=no"
  );
}else{
  alert('Your browser isn\'t supported!');
}
```

All of the browsers (*like Chrome, Firefox, Opera...*) that work with Netscape return this error

**Take note that the error is:** *uncaught ReferenceError: netscape is not defined*

And for those who don't know what is Netscape, read this question's answer:

[Why does JavaScript navigator.appName return Netscape for Safari, Firefox and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573881/why-does-javascript-navigator-appname-return-netscape-for-safari-firefox-and-ch)

**EDIT:**

New question, how can I get the *UniversalBrowserWrite* **Privilege** in Chrome, Firefox, Opera...?

Comment: What browser? What error?

Comment: Netscape? As in Netscape that has been dead for 20 years?

Comment: "this error" … you still haven't told us what that error message is

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Opera and a lot of browsers use Netscape...

Comment: The error message is under ```netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");```

Comment: This "Netscape" is not commonly known component in browsers, can you shead some light on that? Perhaps link to some documentation ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigator.appName == "Netscape"` is not a reliable test for support for the `netscape` object. Plenty of browsers set Netscape as the `appName` to work around [terrible browser sniffing code](https://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/). If you want to test for a feature, then test *for the feature* (e.g. `if (typeof netscape !== 'undefined')`,

In browsers which *do* support it (which I think is limited to Firefox), support for `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager` was removed [many years ago](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2012/privilege-manager-has-been-disabled/) for security reasons.

Comment: Yeah, so how can I get the *UniversalBrowserWrite* Privilege in Chrome, Firefox, Opera...?

Comment: @SharedAccount — You can't. From the link:  "You should find a workaround like an add-on where privileges are actually required."

Comment: Thanks Quentin, you've ruined my weekend. The linked article made me remember all that again; ActiveX, JSSS, CSS Safety Lists ...